# How to get size of jQuery object

Tags: jquery, object, size

I'm saving key-value pairs in div container by using:

```
$( '#div_id').data( key, value);
```

At the end I need to check if anything is stored in this div container.

So first I get the content by calling:

```
var data = $( '#div_id').data();
```

Then to check its size with data.length or data.size.

But both functions don't exists. As I know the data function in jquery returns an object, so I should be able to get the size of this object.

How do I get the size of the object returned by the data function in jquery?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402193

Comment: If you want to check if a specific key is in data() use: if ('key_name' in $('#div_id').data())

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Objects do not have a "size". You could count its properties, though:

```
function getPropertyCount(obj) {
    var count = 0,
        key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
alert(getPropertyCount(data));
```

Comment: Should that be `for (var key in obj) {` ?

Comment: I guess he worries more about that `data` is not declared anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: @jAndy: Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best idea to store those key/value pairs at this level on the object/node.

```
var data = $( '#div_id').data();
```

returns all data that is attached to this `node`, this would include `event handlers` for instance of there are any.

So the best solution is to create an object which contains all of your data:

```
$('#div_id').data('mydata', {});
/* ... */
$('#div_id').data('mydata')[key] = value;
```

To your actual question. Plain Javascript objects do not own a `.length` property. You have to check that for yourself, looping over the keys:

```
var mylen = 0;
for(var prop in $('#div_id').data('mydata')) {
    mylen++;  
}
```

This should be improved by also checking and calling the `.hasOwnProperty()` method which makes sure that the current property is not inheritated from somewhere in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what "keys" you were using? if so, just check the keys, if not, [store an Object or Array instead](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

e.g.

```
var myStuff = {};
myStuff.date = new Date();
myStuff.name = "Santa Claus";
myStuff.lifeStory = "Once upon a time...";
$('#div_id').data('myData', myStuff);
```

Then when you need it back out, just grab that one key...

```
var data = $('#div_id').data('myData');
```

Keep in mind, that JavaScript Objects/"Maps" don't have a "length" or "size" method/property, so if you need to check if it contains something, a generic function like this should work.

```
function isObjEmpty(obj){
  for(var i in obj){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Objects doesn't have an length property. But you could easily calculate it with a simple jQuery function.

```
$.fn.dataLength = function () {
    var i,
        n = 0,
        t = $(this);
    for (i in t.data()) {
        n += 1;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Then use it with $('#div_id').dataLength()

**EDIT**:

Mind the other answers about the data-structure in .data and the check for .hasOwnProperty